# Accessing environment variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I would like to set environment variable for  Facebook API like so:

```
   export FACEBOOK_APP_ID=1234
   export FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET=6e81
```

When I `printenv`, I can see these two variables.

However, when I call it in Rails app as follow:

```
provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'],  ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET']
```

I got issue with Facebook, saying:

```
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
```

This means that somehow, ENV couldn't access my environment variables. I also try:

```
provider :facebook, 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID',  'FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'
```

but this doesn't work for me either. If I replace `ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']` with `'1234'`, then there's no issue.

What might go wrong with ENV[]? How can I solve problem?

Comment: Launch the rails console and type `ENV` and see if your environment variable is listed in the hash.

Comment: Thanks Harish. I don't see my FACEBOOK variables there. What should I do?

Comment: When I encounter such issues its is mostly because the rails console/server was launched before the environment variable was set OR the environment variable was set in a different console OR environment variable was set incorrectly.

Comment: I restarted my Terminal, rerun `printenv` and found that environment variables I set earlier were gone. When I set them again with export, and restart `console`, ENV still does not contain these two variables.

Comment: @AdamNYC have you managed to fix this? I got into a similar problem and can't find a working solution.

Comment: @magnum2002: I can't manage to fix it, so I put these environment variables in config/local_env.yml file.

Comment: Thank you @HarishShetty, I didn't load another terminal!